# How to setup kdiff3 in Mac OS?

Tags: git, git-diff, osx-leopard, kdiff3, git-difftool

In`.gitconfig` file I setup up the git diff as follows:

```
[diff]
    tool = kdiff3

[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = path_directory/kdiff3.app
```

In this setting kdiff is not accessible and I get the following **error** when I run in terminal

```
>> git difftool
The diff tool kdiff3 is not available as 'Kdiff_local_software_path/kdiff3.app'
fatal: external diff died, stopping at modified_file
```

Do you have any suggestion I can fix this issue ? In my current setup Mac OS 10.10.5 git diff tool is `git merge tool` that I want to replace with kdiff.

Comment: Is kdiff3 installed?

Comment: @hjpotter92 It is not installed. I unarchive the  dmg file in my local directory

Comment: @DaveNewton OS X 10.10.5 question updated

Comment: No worries, it just caught me off-guard :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`kdiff3` is generally located at the following location:

```
/Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
```

so, try

```
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
```

If you installed `kdiff` using `brew`, then you'd not need the `difftool` parameter in config for git 1.8 onwards. Just the following would work:

```
[diff]
    tool = kdiff3
```

If you installed `kdiff` mounting the dmg file to `kdiff.app` then set your local path as following:

```
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = directory_path_where_you_installed/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
```

Comment: I have not installed with brew. I have kdiff3.app in my local directory. The problem is if I set my local path it can not find the path. Do you have any suggestion regarding setup the local kdiff3.app path location ?

Comment: @J4cK Update the `path` to reflect the actual location of `kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3`.

Comment: for those who have installed kdiff3 with dmg and having `kdiff3: not found` it may help to add this symbolik link: `ln -s /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3 /usr/local/bin/kdiff3`

Answer (score 14):

1. Download kdiff3 and install as app(drag and drop the kdiff3 into your Applications):
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/files/kdiff3/0.9.98/kdiff3-0.9.98-MacOSX-64Bit.dmg/download
2. Setup git config tool as following, works for me on MacBook Pro:

> git config --global merge.tool kdiff3

and:

> git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.cmd
>   '/Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3 $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE
>   -o $MERGED'

Comment: This didn't help for me.

Comment: I checked that /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3 actually exists, so that cannot be the problem. I tried to edit in the .gitconfig file, but that is reset each time I start Sourcetree, so that doesn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: Worked for me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This works + going to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General -> press the button to open kdiff3 anyway if you hit a security error trying to open it.

Answer (score 11):

1. #### First check whether `kdiff3` is installed and recognized by `git`:

   ```sh
   $ type -a kdiff3
   -bash: type: kdiff3: not found
   ```

   In cases where `kdiff3` is not installed in macOS, `git` will also show following messages:

   ```sh
   $ git difftool --tool-help
   $ # OR (both command would do)
   $ git mergetool --tool-help
   'git mergetool --tool=<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
           emerge
           opendiff
           vimdiff
           vimdiff2
           vimdiff3

   The following tools are valid, **but not currently available**:
           ...
           gvimdiff3
           kdiff3
           meld
           ...

   Some of the tools listed above only work in a windowed
   environment. If run in a terminal-only session, they will fail.
   ```

---

2. #### Then we should install `kdiff3`, there are many ways to do it:

   - by using [MacPort](https://www.macports.org/)
   - by using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)
   - by downloading [SourceForge dmg package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kdiff3/files/kdiff3)
   - building from source
   - etc.

   I personally prefer [MacPort](https://www.macports.org/):

   ```sh
   $ port search kdiff3
   kdiff3 @0.9.98_4 (devel)
       kdiff3 is a file comparing and merging tool.
   $ sudo port install kdiff3
   ...installing process...
   ```

   After this, `kdiff3` should be available to macOS and `git`

   ```sh
   $ type -a kdiff3
   kdiff3 is /opt/local/bin/kdiff3
   $ git difftool --tool-help
   'git difftool --tool=<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
           emerge
           kdiff3
           opendiff
           ...
   ```

---

3. #### Finally, make sure the correct configuration for `git`:

   ```
   [diff]
       tool = kdiff3
   [difftool]
       prompt = false
   [merge]
       tool = kdiff3
       conflictstyle = diff3
   ```

Comment: for those who have installed kdiff3 with dmg and having `kdiff3: not found` it may help to add this symbolik link: `ln -s /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3 /usr/local/bin/kdiff3`

Comment: There seems to be a problem when installing on M1 Macs: Error: Cannot install kdiff3 for the arch 'arm64' because
Error: its dependency qt4-mac only supports the archs 'ppc ppc64 i386 x86_64'.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to add any paths to your gitconfig as described in the other answers.
This is all you need to configure in you .gitconfig

```
[diff]
    guitool = kdiff3
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
```

Assuming you have homebrew installed on your machine:

```
brew update
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew cask install kdiff3
```

Explanation:

1. setup to use cask

   ```
   brew tap caskroom/cask
   ```
2. downloads kdiff3, moves it to your Applications dir and links kdiff3.sh to /usr/local/bin/kdiff3

   ```
   brew cask install kdiff3
   ```

Comment: As of August 2019 the following error is thrown
`Error: Cask 'kdiff3' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952344/brew-cask-install-kdiff3-fails

Answer (score 1):

Here are updated commands if you are installing kdiff3 using brew

brew tap homebrew/cask

brew install kdiff3 --cask

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my 5 cents to this answer if you do not have homebrew follow these steps from [appstore official site](https://macappstore.org/kdiff3/) it will take a few minutes to download and install all the necessary packages.

After running the second step you need to follow the instructions that the terminal shows you after everything was downloaded and installed(there are 3 more steps to execute in the terminal).

In source tree then you will be able to select kdiff3 as the default diff merge tool.

If running the merge tool program for the first time you might need to execute it from the applications folder yourself by right clicking the file and select the open option in order to give the diff tool app the necessary permission to be executed every time.