# kdiff3 mergetool produces untracked files

Tags: git, kdiff3, git-untracked

This is my first time using kdiff3 merge tool.

I am using mac os, so I installed kdiff3 with homebrew with the manual below.

http://www.ryanwright.me/cookbook/mac/homebrew/kdiff3

I have added merge.tool kdiff3 in my .gitconfig

```
git config --global merge.tool kdiff3
```

and I also have added

```
[diff]
    tool = kdiff3
```

as suggested in [How to setup kdiff3 in Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722301/how-to-setup-kdiff3-in-mac-os)

kdiff3 successfully turned on with the command.

```
git mergetool
```

but the problem is that, when I check the status,

```
git status
```

unknown untracked files are produced

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   t1.c

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    t1_BACKUP_47497.c
    t1_BASE_47497.c
    t1_LOCAL_47497.c
    t1_REMOTE_47497.c
```

I cannot figure out what that untracked files are.

Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Comment: Seems they are temporary files created when kdiff3 is running. You can just leave them alone or add them to gitignore.

Comment: appreciate that. I removed those files, and reproductions are not occurring. gitignore might be a good way to solve this issue. thanks.