# How to set up kdiff3 on Mac Mojave?

Tags: git, kdiff3

I have installed kdiff3 in my Applications directory. What changes should I do now to my ~/.gitconfig file so kdiff3 takes care of diff as well as merge issues?

got answer in : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33722631/1841181

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup kdiff3 in Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722301/how-to-setup-kdiff3-in-mac-os)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for difftool command.

```
git difftool --help
```

You can try some things and come again with the results if you still need help.

Comment: got the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33722631/1841181