# brew cask install kdiff3 fails

Tags: macos, homebrew, kdiff3

```
brew cask install kdiff3
Error: Cask 'kdiff3' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.

brew install kdiff3
Error: No available formula with the name "kdiff3"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

brew search kdiff3
No formula or cask found for "kdiff3".
Closed pull requests:
tap_migrations: remove kdiff3 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/43798)
Delete kdiff3.rb (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/67726)
p4v 18.3-1719707: Add CLI-accessible commands to work with Git out of the box (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/54957)
Update kdiff3 to 0.9.98 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/31404)
Update kdiff3 - add shimscript (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/35967)
Secure URLs (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/52975)
kdiff3 migrated to cask (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/3335)
kdiff3 0.9.98 (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/31147)
Added formula kdiff3 (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/5724)
Update kdiff3 to 0.9.97 (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/14268)
diffpdf: Bump to 2.1.3 (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/24912)
Doctor: suggest stashing untracked files rather than deleting (https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/pull/15837)
Upgrade kdiff3 to 0.9.98 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/5231)
Add binary link to kdiff3 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/3476)
Add kdiff3.app (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/1847)
bugfix: kdiff3 cask name incorrect (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/1990)
Create kdiff3 v0.9.97 cask (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/1292)
New Cask Kdiff3 v0.9.97 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/1287)
More efficient listing of installed Casks (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/1778)

brew --version
Homebrew 2.1.16
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 2a800; last commit 2019-11-20)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 40638; last commit 2019-11-20)
```

So how to install kdiff3 using brew on mac os?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`kdiff3` was [removed from Homebrew’s packages in August 2019](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/pull/67726) because its last compatible version is five years old. If you really want to install it, you can checkout [the formula (package) file in the GitHub repo from just before its removal](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/6a96e5ea44803e52a43c0c89242390f75d1581ab/Casks/kdiff3.rb). You can either copy the file locally or directly use the URL:

```
brew cask install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/6a96e5ea44803e52a43c0c89242390f75d1581ab/Casks/kdiff3.rb
```

Comment: Also this procedure should be done to run kdiff3 https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23033#issuecomment-540417305

Comment: This seems to be for an older version. You can download and install the latest version from this link without using brew: https://download.kde.org/stable/kdiff3/